ARIMA time series: different results between SAS and Python
I am trying to translate a time series analysis program from SAS to Python.
In SAS, I am using a proc arima as shown below:
%let dummy_regr = gen_1 gen_2 feb marz apr mag giu ago set ott nov dic_1 dic_2 
fest_1 fest_2 pre_fest_1 pre_fest_2 post_fest_1 post_fest_2;
%let continue_regr= t seno coseno ;

proc arima data=per_arima;
identify var=variabile_arma crosscorr=(&dummy_regr &continue_regr);
estimate p=1 q=1 d=0  input=(&dummy_regr &continue_regr) ;        
forecast  lead = 365 id=progr_settimane interval=day printall out=risultato ;
run;
quit;

I translated this instruction into Python as follows:
dummy_regr = ['gen_1', 'gen_2', 'feb', 'marz', 'apr', 'mag', 'giu', 'ago', 
          'set', 'ott', 'nov', 'dic_1', 'dic_2', 'fest_1', 'fest_2', 
          'pre_fest_1', 'pre_fest_2', 'post_fest_1', 'post_fest_2']
continue_regr = ['seno', 'coseno', 't']
order_arima = (1, 0, 1)
exog_1 = sintesi_df[dummy_regr + continue_regr]
ts = sub_sintesi_df['variabile_arma'].copy()
model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(ts, order=order_arima, exog=exog_1)
arma_results = model.fit()
sub_sintesi_df['previsti'] = arma_results.predict(exog=exog_1).iloc[:len(sub_sintesi_df)]
sub_sintesi_df['residui'] = sub_sintesi_df['variabile_arma'] - sub_sintesi_df['previsti']
conf_ctrl = arma_results.get_prediction(exog=exog_1).conf_int(alpha=0.05)
conf_ctrl.columns = ['previsti_lower', 'previsti_upper']

I notice some differences (although modest) in the forecast and the confidence intervals.
Is there any option to make the result in Python identical to the one provided by SAS?
Thanks

Your SAS model uses conditional least squares. statsmodels ARIMA uses maximum likelihood estimation. Try changing the SAS model to MLE and see if they match using the method=ml option in your estimate statement. If you cannot use MLE in your SAS model because it's already defined and should not be changed due to business reasons, it's unlikely your models will ever match. statsmodels cannot use CLS estimates as far as I am aware.
